# what is meant by this Unable to analyze EL expression due to lexical analysis error?

Tags: jsp

i m trying this but getting some lexical analysis error

```
enter code here



<td><a href="${edit}"><c:out value="${fn:replace(record.question,'IMAGE','<img src="${questionPath}"/>'/></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ${} when you're already inside an EL expression.

Moreover, I guess that the goal of this is to generate an `<img>` HTML tag. Anc c:out is precisely used to escape HTML special character, so you shouldn't embed this into a c:out tag.

This should do what you want:

```
${fn:replace(record.question,
             'IMAGE',
             '<img src="' + fn:escapeXml(questionPath) + '"/>') }
```